# Best logging solution for Workato workflows?

Tags: logging, workato, reltio

I am trying to write logs out for a loop process and for each rown log if it succeeds or fails and why.  There is a logging step in Workato, but I cannot actually find where the whole log is after the job is completed.  Anybody know?

Ideally I would like to write out a user friendly job report and email or post it back to the team who created the file so they can see the errors.  Is there a way to do that? TIA

Answer (score 0):

To view the Logs page, you must have either of the following privileges:

- The **Admin system role**, or
- The **Logs privilege**, located in Platform Tools

To find the logs page, navigate to **Tools > Logs**.

From your description, it seems that you need more detailed logging, like in the loop processes. For this, you can use custom actions to log specific information.

You can add actions in your recipe to create log messages for each iteration of a loop. This can be done by using HTTP actions to send log data to an external logging system or by writing to a database.

Please refer to the following document for more information.

https://docs.workato.com/features/logging-service.html